# What is the `e` parameter passed to the d3.js force tick callback function?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

below is a normal example of tick function:

```
function tick(e) {
     nodes
      .each(cluster(10 * e.alpha * e.alpha));
}
```

who can tell me the definition of "e"? What properties does it have?
I can't find any description of "e", and what's the meaning of e.alpha. Yes, I used google but with no results.

---

Thanks for the help you gave below.

I'm copying some code, which  use

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(nodes)
        .size([width, height])
        .charge(-70)
        .gravity(0.1)
        .on("tick", tick)
        .start();
```

so it's just the case you guess. I'm new to d3, a skim of force.layout API didn't give me any clue. Thanks for your precious time!

Comment: Search for `e.alpha` within [this post](http://flowingdata.com/2012/08/02/how-to-make-an-interactive-network-visualization/).

Comment: Please give more context about where you found this function.  Presenting a function on its own doesn't tell you anything about the nature of the parameter that will be passed to it.  I've made a reasonable guess in my answer, but the question as is should be closed for not containing sufficient information to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 14):

Without the full context of your "normal" function, this is a bit of a guess, but here goes:

`tick` is used in many contexts within d3.  The inlcusion of [`alpha`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#alpha) suggests that this is a [force layout tick function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#on), which is called by the force layout object on a tick event, in which case `e` would be the tick event object.

There is not a lot of documentation about the tick event, as most examples don't use it.  If you inspect the [source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/48ad44fdeef32b518c6271bb99a9aed376c1a1d6/src/layout/force.js), you will see

```
// A rudimentary force layout using Gauss-Seidel.
d3.layout.force = function() {                       //line 11
    var force = {},
        event = d3.dispatch("start", "tick", "end"); 
    /* ... */
    force.tick = function() {                        //line 58
        // simulated annealing, basically
        if ((alpha *= .99) < .005) {
          event.end({type: "end", alpha: alpha = 0});
          return true;
        }
        /* code to implement default force layout adjustments */
        event.tick({type: "tick", alpha: alpha});   //line 128
    };
    /* ... */
    return d3.rebind(force, event, "on");           //line 305
};
```

In other words, the tick event is one of three types of custom event created within the d3 source code using the [d3.dispatch](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals#events) process.  The `tick` event in particular is dispatched at the end of the internal tick function, and only contains one custom property: the current `alpha` parameter within the force layout.  In order that these events actually go anywhere, the `on` method of the event dispatcher object is [rebound](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals#rebind) on to the force layout object, so that the user can register listener functions for the custom events.

If all that is way too much d3 internals for you, just focus on these details:

- `e` is a custom event object passed to your tick function every time it is called
- `e.alpha` is the force layout's current alpha value, which by default starts at 0.1 and gets reduced (according to the `friction` parameter) at each tick until it drops below 0.005 and the layout freezes:

  > Internally, the layout uses a cooling parameter `alpha` which controls the layout temperature: as the physical simulation converges on a stable layout, the temperature drops, causing nodes to move more slowly. Eventually, `alpha` drops below a threshold and the simulation stops completely, freeing the CPU and avoiding battery drain.  ([From the API wiki for `force.start`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#start))

Comment: Sorry, but I have to thank you with more than an upvote.  At present this is, afaik, the only public documentation of what is passed to a parameterized `on("tick"` function, and of what the `alpha` component means (other than the d3 source code).  `e.alpha` is used in several examples (e.g. Google "d3 multiple force layouts") without any explanation.  So I wish I could give more than one vote to this answer.   (Not that you're in need of SO rep.)   Unfortunately, this answer doesn't come up easily in Google searches. But it's not hard to find in an SO search.

Comment: Thanks @Mars.  And you got me to do something I should have done back in October: I [updated the d3 API wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#on) to include this information, so it should be easier to find in the future!

Comment: Cool.  (I still find your answer here very helpful.  Since I don't understand the whole dispatch thing yet, it's useful to see an explanation that explicitly references a definition of `tick` that takes a parameter.)

Comment: Does anyone know if the tick event is retained in v4?